# Is it possible to select subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ser.id) *
FROM server ser
LEFT JOIN subscription sub ON ser.id = sub.server_id
WHERE (
    COUNT(SELECT err.id FROM error err WHERE ser.id = err.id) > 0
    OR SUM(SELECT pay.amount FROM payment pay WHERE ser.id = pay.id) > 0
);
```

Here, a list of unique servers that are being subscribed to and that has errors or payments is returned.

However, instead of returning all server columns (*), I want to return the server id, the number of errors and the sum of payments. For example, the initial selection should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ser.id) ser.id, countErrors, sumPayments
```

Selecting ser.id is straight forward, but how can countErrors and sumPayments be selected from the aggregate functions "count" and "sum" (considering that they are conditions in a WHERE clause)?

I imagined the "where" conditions would look something like this:

```
    COUNT(SELECT err.id FROM error err WHERE ser.id = err.id) AS countErrors  > 0
    OR SUM(SELECT pay.amount FROM payment pay WHERE ser.id = pay.id) AS sumPayments > 0
```

Is it possible to do this? If so, how can it be achieved?

Test data is shown below:

```
server
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+

subscription
+----+-----------+
| id | server_id |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | 2         |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | 2         |
+----+-----------+
| 4  | 3         |
+----+-----------+
| 5  | 3         |
+----+-----------+

error
+----+-----------+
| id | server_id |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 1         |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | 4         |
+----+-----------+

payment
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | server_id | amount |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 1  | 1         | 200    |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 2  | 2         | 200    |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 3  | 2         | 100    |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Wanted result from test data:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| server_id | countErrors | sumPayments |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1         | 1           | 200         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 2         | 0           | 300         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

- Server#4 has no subscription, so it should be left out.
- Server#3 has a subscription, but no errors or payments, so should be left out.
- Server#1 and server#2 both have subscription and payments and/or errors.

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll play around with the answer that has been posted first to see if it works.

Comment: No, you should clarify your question with data for the benefit of all.  Your question will not help many people without data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is the test data on correct format?

Comment: How does server #1 end up with a payment sum of 200, while server #2 has a sum of 300?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That was my bad. Should be corrected now. Server#1 should have 1 payment a la 200 while server#2 should have 2 payments a la 100 and 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I would just write your query as follows.  Perform the aggregation of errors and payments in separate bona fide subqueries, and join to them.  Also, there is a join to the `subscription` table, but this only exists to filter off servers having no subscription.  Finally, the `WHERE` clause removes any servers which do not either have some errors or payments.

```
SELECT
    s.id AS server_id,
    COALESCE(e.countErrors, 0) AS countErrors,
    COALESCE(p.sumPayments, 0) AS sumPayments
FROM server s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT server_id
    FROM subscription
) su
    ON s.id = su.server_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT server_id, COUNT(*) AS countErrors
    FROM error
    GROUP BY server_id
) e
    ON s.id = e.server_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT server_id, SUM(amount) AS sumPayments
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY server_id
) p
    ON s.id = p.server_id
WHERE
    p.sumPayments > 0 OR
    e.countErrors > 0
ORDER BY
    s.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: If "payment" got another column, lets call it "payment_type", and I want to return "sumPaymentTypeA", "sumPaymentTypeB", "sumPaymentTypeC" etc. Is the best practice to create a new JOIN-query for each "payment_type"? Or is it possible to do something more elegant within the same JOIN-query?

Comment: You might be able to just aggregate the sub payments inside the same subquery.  But I recommend opening a new question if you need a different query.

Comment: I found a way to do it: "SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS sumPaymentTypeA" etc. It's simple and works perfectly fine. The question is just whether there is a more efficient/elegant way to do it or not. I assume this is fine enough though, so I'll stick with it unless if the universe starts to cry...

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here is to put the COUNT outside of the SELECT, it needs to go inside:

```
(SELECT COUNT(err.id) FROM error err WHERE ser.id = err.id) > 0
    OR (SELECT SUM(pay.amount) FROM payment pay WHERE ser.id = pay.id) > 0
```

Comment: You mean like this: SELECT COUNT(err.id) AS countError FROM error err WHERE ser.id = err.id) > 0? At least this compiles. However, I get an error when I put SELECT DISTINCT ON (ser.id) ser.id, countErrors. It says that countErrors doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarcusPersson If you want to select that data, put the subselect in a JOIN instead of the where clause.

Comment: Right. However, if I have lets say, 10 WHERE conditions that I need to convert like this, that's a lot of joins. Is this a good solution performance wise?

Comment: @MarcusPersson It makes no difference, if anything the WHERE will be more costly. But the SQL engine should plan both the same way.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it out!